How can document settings/metadata be saved in SwiftData/SwiftUI?
Background: I had an old CoreData, document-based app where it was expected each document would apply to a specific year, in a specific state/province. It made the most sense to save the year and location on a per-document basis, outside of the CoreData model. I managed use the document's metadata dictionary, accessed via the NSPersistentStore, as described in this question: How can document-based settings be stored?
In more detail, the code looked like this:
class Document: NSPersistentDocument {
    //other let/var here
    
    var persistentStore: NSPersistentStore? {
        if let stores = self.managedObjectContext?.persistentStoreCoordinator?.persistentStores {
            if stores != [] {
                return stores[0]
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    @objc dynamic var documentYear = 2011 {
        didSet {
            setMetaData(documentYear as AnyObject, forKey: "year")
        }
    }
    
    @objc dynamic var documentProvince = 3 {
        didSet {
            setMetaData(documentProvince as AnyObject, forKey: "province")
        }
    }
    
    func setMetaData(_ object: AnyObject, forKey key: String) {
        if persistentStore != nil {
            var metadataDict = persistentStore!.metadata
            if metadataDict?[key] == nil || (metadataDict?[key] as! NSNumber) != (object as! NSNumber) {
                metadataDict?[key] = object
                persistentStore!.metadata = metadataDict
                updateChangeCount(.changeDone)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getMetaData() {
        if persistentStore != nil {
            let metadataDict = persistentStore!.metadata
            if metadataDict?["year"] != nil {
                documentYear = metadataDict?["year"] as! Int
            }
            
            if metadataDict?["province"] != nil {
                documentProvince = metadataDict?["province"] as! Int
            }
        }
    }
    
    //other code here
}

I know it's not exactly clean, but that's not the point here...
Problem: Now updating to SwiftData, but trying to keep compatibility with my old files (even if I am basically the only user of this program).
I can't find any documentation about an equivalent to NSPersistentStore in SwiftData/SwiftUI. This seems to mean I can't get the metadata out of my old files (or create new document files with a SwiftUI version, using that previous method). The only mention of metadata in the SwiftData documentation seems to be on the persistent models themselves, which won't help.
I can't see how to subclass the persistent document in SwiftUI anyway, which means the previous method I used in the CoreData version wouldn't work even if I did have an equivalent to NSPersistentStore. Additionally, if I can't subclass the document, I don't seem to have an alternative place to save document settings even outside the Persistent Store (if I were willing to break compatibility with old documents).
Question: Can document settings or metadata be used in SwiftData/SwiftUI, and if so, how? Is there a way to access the Persistent Store metadata that existed in my old CoreData files? Or is this something that just isn't possible yet, pending this year's WWDC, and my app's migration to SwiftData will have to wait?

Did you ever find a solution to this?

I apologise in advance - this is a kludge - but the OP has identified a serious failing in SwiftData in a document architecture: the inability to save per document settings.
The issue as seen from the OP's perspective is that there is no equivalent of CoreData's metadata (and that is the ultimately correct way to solve this) - but another way to look at it is that any @Model class @Query returns an array, not a single instance, as would be needed for document settings.
This kludge puts the settings in a @Model class and then restricts the creation of those to a single instance, inserting and returning a default instance if the container is empty. It's awful, but if you need per document settings, you're going to have to do something...
@Model
final public class Settings {
    var sortModeRaw: String = SortMode.sequence.rawValue
    // etc...
}

/// Input `settings` is returned by a regular `@Query`
/// You must, of course, *never* insert settings manually!
func singleSettings(_ settings: [Settings], in modelContext: ModelContext) -> Settings {
    if let s = settings.first {
        // assert(settings.count < 2)
        return s
    } else {
        let s = Settings()
        modelContext.insert(s)
        do {
            try modelContext.save()
        } catch let e {
            print(e.localizedDescription)
        }
        return s
    }
}

Footnote
A possibility that I investigated before cobbling this together was the extended form of the DocumentGroup invocation with the prepareDocument closure, however it isn't called on OSX, only on iOS, and I haven't got it to work effectively on iOS. Here's what I tried:
DocumentGroup(editing: [CatalogueEntry.self, Settings.self],
              contentType: .urbanExplorer,
              editor: { ContentView() },
              prepareDocument: { modelContext in
    // This doesn't seem to get called on OSX, but does on iOS?
    var descriptor = FetchDescriptor<Settings>()
    descriptor.fetchLimit = 1

    do {
        let settings = try modelContext.fetch(descriptor)
        print("Settings: \(settings.count)")
        if settings.count == 0 {
            modelContext.insert(Settings())
            try modelContext.save()
            print("Default data inserted!")
        } else {
            print("We already have data!")
        }
    } catch let e {
        print(e.localizedDescription)
    }
})

If it worked it might be slightly cleaner than the other kludge, but you're still going to have to just take the .first - it's still not really a proper solution.

This looks like it could work. I'd actually considered something similar, but didn't try it because I don't know how to pull the per-document settings out of the documents I've already created on the older, CoreData version of the program, so they'd no longer be compatible. I ended up putting the whole project on hold, hoping Apple would add PersistentStore to SwiftData. I may see about trying this suggestion soon, though, since it's unlikely Apple will add it mid-upgrade-cycle.

It does work in my project, though I hear your issue about migrating it from CoreData. Obviously it is extremely fragile in a development environment (2 instances will completely break it as there is no guarantee of order retrieval), but it should be robust if dirty in production
